# Fancy-preview and pdfTex error during compiling: reading image field failed

Tags: errors, compilation-error, fancytooltips

The code I'm using is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Lemma}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref} % Important!

\bibliography{biblio}

\usepackage[inactive]{fancytooltips}
\begin{document}

This is \tooltip*{\LaTeX}{lion} system.

\begin{theorem}[Lemma from \cite{goossens93}]\label{lemma}
  If $k<0$, then
  \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:1}
    x^2+k<x^2
  \end{equation}
  for every real number $x$.
\end{theorem}


Inequality \eqref{eq:1} in Lemma \ref{lemma} can be proved easily. Is
more general than \cite[Thm. 3.1]{knuth79}.

\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:2}
    x^2+k_1<x^2
  \end{equation}


\clearpage
See Lemma~\ref{lemma}, equation~(\ref{eq:1}). Compare also (\ref{eq:2}).
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The following is the log file for my example:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.7.23)  23 JUL 2020 07:47
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**\AtBeginDocument{\input fancy-preview-biblatex-settings.tex}\RequirePackage{e
toolbox}\PassOptionsToPackage{active,mouseover,movetips,filename=minimal,previe
wall,nosoap}{fancytooltips}\AtEndPreamble{\usepackage{fancytooltips}\hypersetup
{colorlinks=true}}\input minimal

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/07/15 v2.5i e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count168
) (./minimal.tex
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count169
\c@section=\count170
\c@subsection=\count171
\c@subsubsection=\count172
\c@paragraph=\count173
\c@subparagraph=\count174
\c@figure=\count175
\c@table=\count176
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2020/01/20 v2.17e AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip49

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks15
\ex@=\dimen135
))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen136
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count177
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 227.
\uproot@=\count178
\leftroot@=\count179
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 389.
\classnum@=\count180
\DOTSCASE@=\count181
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 486.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 489.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 610.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box45
\strutbox@=\box46
\big@size=\dimen137
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 733.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 734.
\macc@depth=\count182
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count183
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count184
\dspbrk@lvl=\count185
\tag@help=\toks16
\row@=\count186
\column@=\count187
\maxfields@=\count188
\andhelp@=\toks17
\eqnshift@=\dimen138
\alignsep@=\dimen139
\tagshift@=\dimen140
\tagwidth@=\dimen141
\totwidth@=\dimen142
\lineht@=\dimen143
\@envbody=\toks18
\multlinegap=\skip50
\multlinetaggap=\skip51
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks19
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2859.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2860.
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty
Package: amsthm 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
\thm@style=\toks20
\thm@bodyfont=\toks21
\thm@headfont=\toks22
\thm@notefont=\toks23
\thm@headpunct=\toks24
\thm@preskip=\skip52
\thm@postskip=\skip53
\thm@headsep=\skip54
\dth@everypar=\toks25
)
\c@theorem=\count189

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex 2019/12/01 v3.14 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2019/12/15 v1.24 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks26
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2019/11/29 v3.13 Key value format for package options (HO)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count190

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip17
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count191
\c@listtotal=\count192
\c@listcount=\count193
\c@liststart=\count194
\c@liststop=\count195
\c@citecount=\count196
\c@citetotal=\count197
\c@multicitecount=\count198
\c@multicitetotal=\count199
\c@instcount=\count266
\c@maxnames=\count267
\c@minnames=\count268
\c@maxitems=\count269
\c@minitems=\count270
\c@citecounter=\count271
\c@maxcitecounter=\count272
\c@savedcitecounter=\count273
\c@uniquelist=\count274
\c@uniquename=\count275
\c@refsection=\count276
\c@refsegment=\count277
\c@maxextratitle=\count278
\c@maxextratitleyear=\count279
\c@maxextraname=\count280
\c@maxextradate=\count281
\c@maxextraalpha=\count282
\c@abbrvpenalty=\count283
\c@highnamepenalty=\count284
\c@lownamepenalty=\count285
\c@maxparens=\count286
\c@parenlevel=\count287
\blx@tempcnta=\count288
\blx@tempcntb=\count289
\blx@tempcntc=\count290
\blx@maxsection=\count291
\blx@maxsegment@0=\count292
\blx@notetype=\count293
\blx@parenlevel@text=\count294
\blx@parenlevel@foot=\count295
\blx@sectionciteorder@0=\count296
\blx@entrysetcounter=\count297
\labelnumberwidth=\skip55
\labelalphawidth=\skip56
\biblabelsep=\skip57
\bibitemsep=\skip58
\bibnamesep=\skip59
\bibinitsep=\skip60
\bibparsep=\skip61
\bibhang=\skip62
\blx@bcfin=\read2
\blx@bcfout=\write3
\blx@langwohyphens=\language86
\c@mincomprange=\count298
\c@maxcomprange=\count299
\c@mincompwidth=\count300
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def
File: blx-dm.def 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count301
\c@savedafterword=\count302
\c@annotator=\count303
\c@savedannotator=\count304
\c@author=\count305
\c@savedauthor=\count306
\c@bookauthor=\count307
\c@savedbookauthor=\count308
\c@commentator=\count309
\c@savedcommentator=\count310
\c@editor=\count311
\c@savededitor=\count312
\c@editora=\count313
\c@savededitora=\count314
\c@editorb=\count315
\c@savededitorb=\count316
\c@editorc=\count317
\c@savededitorc=\count318
\c@foreword=\count319
\c@savedforeword=\count320
\c@holder=\count321
\c@savedholder=\count322
\c@introduction=\count323
\c@savedintroduction=\count324
\c@namea=\count325
\c@savednamea=\count326
\c@nameb=\count327
\c@savednameb=\count328
\c@namec=\count329
\c@savednamec=\count330
\c@translator=\count331
\c@savedtranslator=\count332
\c@shortauthor=\count333
\c@savedshortauthor=\count334
\c@shorteditor=\count335
\c@savedshorteditor=\count336
\c@labelname=\count337
\c@savedlabelname=\count338
\c@institution=\count339
\c@savedinstitution=\count340
\c@lista=\count341
\c@savedlista=\count342
\c@listb=\count343
\c@savedlistb=\count344
\c@listc=\count345
\c@savedlistc=\count346
\c@listd=\count347
\c@savedlistd=\count348
\c@liste=\count349
\c@savedliste=\count350
\c@listf=\count351
\c@savedlistf=\count352
\c@location=\count353
\c@savedlocation=\count354
\c@organization=\count355
\c@savedorganization=\count356
\c@origlocation=\count357
\c@savedoriglocation=\count358
\c@origpublisher=\count359
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count360
\c@publisher=\count361
\c@savedpublisher=\count362
\c@language=\count363
\c@savedlanguage=\count364
\c@origlanguage=\count365
\c@savedoriglanguage=\count366
\c@pageref=\count367
\c@savedpageref=\count368
\shorthandwidth=\skip63
\shortjournalwidth=\skip64
\shortserieswidth=\skip65
\shorttitlewidth=\skip66
\shortauthorwidth=\skip67
\shorteditorwidth=\skip68
\locallabelnumberwidth=\skip69
\locallabelalphawidth=\skip70
\localshorthandwidth=\skip71
\localshortjournalwidth=\skip72
\localshortserieswidth=\skip73
\localshorttitlewidth=\skip74
\localshortauthorwidth=\skip75
\localshorteditorwidth=\skip76
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def
File: blx-compat.def 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def
File: biblatex.def 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
\c@textcitecount=\count369
\c@textcitetotal=\count370
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count371
\c@biburlbigbreakpenalty=\count372
\c@biburlbreakpenalty=\count373
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count374
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count375
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count376
\biburlbigskip=\muskip18
\biburlnumskip=\muskip19
\biburlucskip=\muskip20
\biburllcskip=\muskip21
\c@smartand=\count377
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.bbx' found.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
File: numeric.bbx 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx
File: standard.bbx 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count378
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count379
))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.cbx' found.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx
File: numeric.cbx 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex citation style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\supercite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcites'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hypertext links for LaTeX

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen144
\Hy@linkcounter=\count380
\Hy@pagecounter=\count381

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count382
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4464.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4469.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4472.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4479.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4484.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4717.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count383
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5076.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen145

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count384
\Field@Width=\dimen146
\Fld@charsize=\dimen147
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6347.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6352.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6355.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6362.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6367.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6372.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6377.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6417.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6421.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty
Package: atbegshi 2019/12/05 v1.19 At begin shipout hook (HO)
)
\Hy@abspage=\count385
\c@Item=\count386
\c@Hfootnote=\count387
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref driver for pdfTeX

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/atveryend/atveryend.sty
Package: atveryend 2019-12-11 v1.11 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
)
\Fld@listcount=\count388
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count389

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
86.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip77
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancytooltips/fancytooltips.sty
Package: fancytooltips 2012/06/12 v1.12 fancytooltips.dtx file

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen148
\Gin@req@width=\dimen149
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks27
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks28
)
\XKV@depth=\count390
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
\buttontipwidth=\dimen150
\buttontipheight=\dimen151
\fancy@a=\dimen152
\fancy@b=\dimen153
\fancy@layerHshift=\dimen154
\fancy@layerVshift=\dimen155
\fancy@button@Vshift=\dimen156
\fancy@button@Hshift=\dimen157
\pos@fancy@toks=\toks29
\fancycheckcount=\count391

(c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/acrotex/eforms.sty
Package: eforms 2016/07/22 v2.9b Provides general eforms support (dps)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count392
\calc@Bcount=\count393
\calc@Adimen=\dimen158
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen159
\calc@Askip=\skip78
\calc@Bskip=\skip79
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count394
\calc@Cskip=\skip80
)
(c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/acrotex/insdljs.sty
Package: insdljs 2016/07/31 v2.3a Insert Document Level JavaScripts (dps)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty
Package: verbatim 2019/11/10 v1.5r LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
\every@verbatim=\toks30
\verbatim@line=\toks31
\verbatim@in@stream=\read3
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
)
\js@verbatim@out=\write4
\c@dljs@cnt=\count395
\c@dljssegs=\count396
\JStoks=\toks32
\importfdftoks=\toks33
\dljsobjtoks=\toks34
)
(c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/acrotex/taborder.sty
Package: taborder 2009/09/04 v0.1 taborder: Sets the tab order, Acrobat Distill
er only (dps)
)
\eq@tmpbox=\box47
\eq@tmpdima=\dimen160
\eqcenterWidget=\dimen161

(c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/acrotex/epdftex.def))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty
Package: eso-pic 2018/04/12 v2.0h eso-pic (RN)
)
\tooltip@count=\count397
\tooltip@toks=\toks35
\tooltip@pagetoks=\toks36
\@fxtoks=\toks37
\@fytoks=\toks38

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file ./minimal.pdf): reading image file failed
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

In particular, the file can be compiled if I'm not using fancy-preview but cause this error if the command `perl fancy-preview minimal` is used. The code was used on Windows PowerShell. Let me know if I need to provide anything else.

Comment: You've marked hyperref "important".  Does that mean that removing that line removes the error?  Can you remove the other three packages and still get the error?  Do you need to have the theorem and equation, or is the `\tooltip` sufficient to cause the error?

Comment: @Teepeemm As a matter of fact the code is not from my own hand. In addition, this file complies perfectly if you use pdfLeTex to complie. The problem only occurs when you use perl fancy-preview minimal.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.  Can you copy this code to a different file and remove those lines to narrow down what's causing the error?

Comment: @Teepeemm without hyperref the file would not compile. Remove `\usepackage[inactive]{fancytooltips}` or `\usepackage{biblatex}` do not change the error. As a matter of fact, even you replace the content in the document with "hello world", the error (`pdflatex.exe: reading image file failed`) resists.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to make those changes.  Please keep trimming out anything that does not cause that error.

Comment: @Hyacinth I'm facing the same problem. Have you solved that?

Comment: @YijunYuan I gave up a long time ago, not worth the trouble...

Comment: @Hyacinth I emailed the author of fancy-preview, he said that this script is no longer maintained, and there are some better options in modern LaTeX distribution. However, he didn't mention what is the "better option".

Comment: @YijunYuan The tools I'm aware of are all mentioned in his document, namely cooltooltips, pdfcomment, ocgtools, and so on. None of them do what I wanted them to do :( Let me know if there are other things I can use.

Comment: @Hyacinth I have the same feeling as you, that there is nothing new. On the other hand, he didn't respond to my further email. :-(