# Alternative of fancy-preview for mordern TeXLive

Tags: incompatibility, compilation-error, fancytooltips, obsolete, tooltips

The script `fancy-preview` is obsolete and no longer works in the recent TeXLive versions (see, for example, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554762/fancy-preview-and-pdftex-error-during-compiling-reading-image-field-failed)). According to the author of fancy-preview, [there are some better options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554762/fancy-preview-and-pdftex-error-during-compiling-reading-image-field-failed#comment1550913_554762), but [he never mentions what the option is](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554762/fancy-preview-and-pdftex-error-during-compiling-reading-image-field-failed#comment1551284_554762). Since his words are not very convincing, do we have any alternative for `fancy-preview`?

Comment: Is http://user.mendelu.cz/marik/fancy-preview/ the description of the correct tool? If so, it seems the author there suggests using KaTeX to handle LaTeX-like equations directly in HTML.

Comment: @JosephWright Yes he does say that. However, we still need a LaTeX based solution.